# brand new to python, list comprehension question

Tags: python

I understand some of this I think. It's for a list of 0s and 1s in 10 lists. This is the list values:

```
tenSpikes = [00101],[01100],[10010],[01010],[11100],[00011],[10101],[11111],[11110],[10101]

for trial in range(len(tenSpikeTrains)):
    spikeTimes = [i for i,x in enumerate (tenSpikeTrains[trial]) if x==1]
```

Questions:

- `for trial in range(len(tenspikes))` is to iterate through the list ten times and each iteration is held in `trial` as 0,1,2..etc right?
- Can someone walk me through `[i for i,x in enumerate tenSpikeTrains[trial] if x==1]`
- Why are there 2 i's? What do the i's mean in this for loop, is it still holding the index? I see it's trying to pull the values where x==1 and is holding the index somehow. Which variables hold the values? Maybe someone can explain this for me?

Comment: what do you mean why are their two `i`s? What exactly do you you not understand? Do you understand how list comprehensions work? Do you understand what `enumerate` does? StackOverfloiw isn't really a place for people to explain to you pieces of code line by line, you should be asking a *specific* question, and show that you've done at least some research. Don't ask multiple questions. Check out [ask] and the [help] for how to write a question that will be received well. Newbie questions are fine, but please put some effort into following the guidelines

Comment: `00101` is illegal in Python. Did you mean `"00101"`?

Comment: You're not allowed to walk me through [i for i,x in enumerate tenSpikeTrains[trial] if x==1]. Why not? It would save me hours

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is a way of filtering or modifying an iterable to create a different one. These can be easily converted into for loops which are often more familiar to people.
You can rewrite
`spikeTimes = [i for i,x in enumerate(tenSpikeTrains[trial]) if x==1]`
as

```py
spikeTimes = []
for i, x in enumerate(tenSpikeTrains[trial]):
    if x == 1:
        spikeTimes.append(i)
```

The first part of the comprehension is `i`. This is the value that is added to the list. The second part is `i, x` these are the two variables that you are iterating with. Third is `enumerate(tenSpikeTrains[trial])`. That is what you are iterating over. And finally, `if x == 1` only adds the first value to the list if this results in true. The last part is optional and can be left off if you don't want to filter it.

Comment: "list comprehension is mostly just a for loop on one line." *No it is not*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Its less versitile obviously, you can only make lists with it and there are tons of nuances like scope and other things. What differences do you think are critical for someone just learning about them to know?

Comment: List comprehensions are functional programming contructs to express mapping/filtering operations over an iterable to produce a list. A for-loop is a basic control-flow statement used to iterate over iterable objects. **You should not be thinking of list comprehensions as "one line for-loops"**. That isn't what they are for, and it leads to all sorts of terrible code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's fair. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think the best and most actionable way to explain it to new users is "in Python, list comprehensions give you functionally the equivalent of one or more nested for-loops, opptionally with if-clauses for filtering, and tuple-unpacking; they are super-powerful, very compact and expressive. Most languages don't have that". Would you edit/quibble with any of that?

Comment: @smci yes, I want to clearly separate for loops which are imperative, from list comprehensions, which are declarative. They are two different paradigms

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes sure we know they're syntactically different, but I'm saying the important point to communicate to new users is "a list-comprehension can functionally do the job of one or several for-loops plus multiple optional if-clauses, and with a nice compact expressive syntax". (When you say "That isn't what they are for, and it leads to all sorts of terrible code...." can you give an example of a misguided list-comprehension?)

Comment: @smci sure, any list comprehension that is used for side-effects. `[print(x) for x in iterable]`

Comment: (@juanpa.arrivillaga: ok agreed, but that's self-evidently not just a list expression that computes a result, which was the OP's context. Could also come up with tortured examples that try to delete/modify a structure as you iterate over it.)

Comment: @smci exactly, because a list comprehension is **not just a for loop** and **shouldn't** be used like a for loop, they are two different things altogether. And people who think that way, that they are "single line for loops", abuse list comprehensions in exactly this sort of way time and again on the Python tag.